paperjs stops sending mouse drag events outside of canvas when using multiple scopes
I'm using paperjs to draw onto a canvas using typescript. I'm using
this.scope = new paper.PaperScope()
this.scope.setup(this.canvas)

to initialize paperjs on the canvas.
Additionally I create a paperjs tool to receive mouse drag messages via
fromEvent<paper.ToolEvent & {event: MouseEvent}>(this.tool, "mousedrag")

When using only a single paperjs-scope and canvas i receive messages all the way when dragging the mouse from inside to outside the canvas (click inside canvas and drag outside), even for mouse moves outside the canvas. However when I create a second canvas a paperjs scope and try again I will only get messages inside the canvas, but as soon as I leave the canvas while dragging I stop receiving messages, so the behaviour is different from the single scope case.
Why is that and how can I continue to receive tool messages when dragging outside the canvas even if I use multiple scopes ?
